# ¿Cómo lidiar con los elementos web que se ocultan cuando intentas inspeccionarlos?

Tags: html, python-3.x, dom, selenium, xpath

Estoy a punto de terminar de desarrollar un programa automatizado en Python y lo único que me detiene es un elemento web que se oculta inmediatamente cuando trato de inspeccionarlo desde una página de **OpenSea** (no puedo compartir el enlace aquí porque requiere estar conectado a mi billetera):

[image: problem]

Hasta ahora solo he logrado obtener el `XPATH` y el `CSS_SELECTOR` de este elemento problemático (`div#tippy-298`) que es el siguiente:

```
button_problematic_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tippy-298"]')
button_problematic_css = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tippy-298')
```

Pero lo que necesito es obtener el `XPATH` o `CSS_SELECTOR` de los Elementos Web que contiene `button_problematic_css`, más específicamente los `Textboxes` de **"Starting"** y **"Ending"**:

[image: desired elements]

Además, por si acaso, el elemento que está encima de `button_problematic_css` se llama "Duración", aquí está su `XPATH`:

```
button_duration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="duration"]').click #después de clickearse despliega el elemento div#tippy-298
```

**Me preguntaba si podría haber algún método para forzar la visibilidad** de este `button_problematic_css` usando `Chrome Console` en la inspección de elementos web, o **usando un método específico** de `Selenium` en `Python3.x` **para descargar inmediatamente todos los elementos web que tiene esta página justo después** `button_problematic_css` está visible.

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es inspeccionar manualmente el elemento, presionando `Ctrl + Shift + C y` y luego haciendo clic en los elementos contenidos en `button_problematic_css`, lo que termina ocultando este elemento incluso antes de hacer clic en su contenido, lo mismo sucede cuando trato de desplegar el contenido de este elemento en el DOM de esta página, simplemente desaparece.

Solo desearía que mi programa pudiera editar las fechas en los cuadros de texto **"Starting"** y **"Ending"**

Comment: Si el elemento se abre cuando le das click en el input de fecha, entonces tienes que simular ese click con selenium, esperar que lo abra y ya tendrás  ese div disponible.

Comment: Correcto, ¿pero cómo obtengo ese div sí cuando lo trato de inspeccionar desaparece? @Ali

Comment: Tal como lo haces en la primera ventana o dandole al elemento del input click derecho > inspeccionar elemento, también puedes utilizar el botoncito de selector el que está en la esquina superior izquierda a lado del de response. Si el elemento desaparece con el hover puedes ayudarte de los modificadores que están en el panel de css por ejemplo el que dice `:hov` que al checkearlo se marcará como siempre hover, ahí también está `:activ` o :focus.

Comment: Sigue sin dejarme poder forzarle los estados en el panel de css, parece que sí clickeo en cualquier zona por fuera del elemento `//*[@id="tippy-298"]` inmediatamente se cierra, no importa que esté usando el DOM @Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varios días de trabajo, logré resolver esto, sucedió que para obtener el XPATH de estos elementos en particular, tuve que usar `Chrome Console` y escribir `$('#duration').click();` .

En este caso, `#duration` es un Selector que se puede usar para obtener el botón del elemento web que le permite editar el período de tiempo que desea establecer cuando se hace clic.

Supongo que la declaración general sería algo como esto:

`$('#su_selector_css').click();`

[image: solved]

Ahora, de esta manera pude mirar más profundamente en el DOM sin hacer que se escondan de nuevo.

Answer (score 2):

Esos cuadritos de texto son input y para editarlos primero toca capturarlos con xPath

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="duration"]').click() # Abres el elemento duration   
inputs= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='date']") # Capturas los input

starting= inputs[1] # inputs[1] es starting y inputs[0] es Ending
starting.click() # Seleccionas el cuadrito starting
starting.send_keys("31") # Envías el día
starting.send_keys("01") # Envías el mes
```

Recuerda que Starting tiene la fecha del día establecida. **Si envías un día menor al que tiene dará error**. Ejemplo, hoy es 30 de enero (30-01) y si envías el 1 de febrero (01-02), da error aunque el mes sea mayor, porque el día es menor a 30.

El código anterior te podría quedar más elegante si lo haces una function como esta:

```py
def set_Ending(date:"dd-mm"): 
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="duration"]').click()
    
    element= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='date']")[1]    
    element.click()   
    for item in date.split("-"):
        element.send_keys(item)
        
set_Ending("20-02")
```